# How to make pyttsx3 stop talking in real-time video capturing in python

Tags: python, pyttsx3

The code below shows the face and produces an output using voices. The problem is I'm unable to stop the voices, I want it to say it only once not for each frame taken
P.S I've tried using a timer but it didn't work.

```
    import cv2
    import pyttsx3
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    voiceEngine = pyttsx3.init()
    while(True):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        success, frame = cap.read()
    
        # Our operations on the frame come here
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        if success:
            voiceEngine.say("hello there")
            voiceEngine.runAndWait()
  
            cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
                break
    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what flags are for.

```
said = False
while True:
...
        if success and not said:
            voiceEngine.say("hello there")
            voiceEngine.runAndWait()
            said = True
```

Comment: Where is there any facial recognition in this code?

Comment: I deleted my first comment by mistake: But how in my case can I let it say my name whenever he sees me, in other words, if my face in the frame he says my name once if I'm off the frame and I come back to the frame he says my name again also once.

Comment: You use a toggle, like a flip flop.  `if face-detected and not said:` / `said = True`, along with `if face-not-detected and said:` / `said = False`.